# some languages in one MSI package

Tags: wix, multilingual

I want to add 2 languages to one MSI package. I use WiX, set

[image]

and

[image]

but in result I get 2 msi packages, instead of one. How to do it in one?

Comment: I set "Cultures to build" to blank in result I get one MSI. But when I execute this MSI from dotNetInstaller language I got english MSI in result (even when dotNetInstaller has russian language). Why?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, WiX doesn't support what you're asking for.

The best workaround I've seen is to create all your localized MSI's (as you do now), use Torch to create transforms from your base installer (the English one, for example) and to embed those MST files into your setup. The technique is outlined on the WiX tutorial, [here](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/transforms/morphing-installers).

As the tutorial describes, you could wrap your MSI with Burn afterwards to detect the current language and specify which transform to apply.